# How to catch the Laravel response after terminating the kernel?

Tags: laravel, request, response, bootstrapping

I want to catch the response of a Laravel application after termination to check if it has the status code 404.
In that case, I want to bootstrap another framework with the same request.

Because I try to bootstrap another framework I really want to make sure that Laravel is completely terminated.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your `public/index.php` file you will see `$response->send()` code. You can wrap it in one if statement like this:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

if($response->getStatusCode() !== 404) {
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
} else {
    // Boot Your Another framework here
}
```

I wrote entire `index.php` file here.

Hope this helps you

Comment: This way you could catch the 404 code, but if it gets in the else statement the Laravel is not going to be terminated. That was my main problem actually

Comment: You can move `$kernel->terminate($request, $response);` from if statement and make another request in laravel as much as you can

Comment: I don't want to make other requests in Laravel. I want to make a new request in another framework. With the code you shared, the application still returns en error containing some Laravel files. So I assume that Laravel is either not terminated completely or there is still some Laravel garbage.

Comment: What you mean 'laravel files' ?  can you show me code?

Comment: `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /Users/luke/sites/framwork_migrate_poc/poc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:907) `

Comment: If this is only supposed to happen on errors, you could leverage the App\Exception\Handler class.  Either in the handle() method, or in a new __destruct() one. Your scenario seems a little odd though. Why are you trying to wire two frameworks together? Maybe there's a better approach.